# read and write txt using scanner java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I´m sorry for being so noob using Java,

I have the following problem:

I want to access 8 txt files and build an array with the same point from each file; for example,

output(1,1)=[file1(point(1,1), file2(point(1,1), file3(point(1,1),file4(point(1,1), file5(point(1,1),file6(point(1,1), file7(point(1,1),file8(point(1,1)]

And so then,

Right now I´m having the following problems...first of all, the code isn´t accessing to the files giving all the time 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ....0.0. Second, I don´t know how to create the output(x,y).txt

Each file input has 1.050.622 points...so it´s needed to create 1.050.622 outputs...

Someone could help me?

this is the code I wrote:

```
package filtros;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

private static final String INPUT_FILE  = "";
private static final String OUTPUT_FILE = "";

public static void main(String[] args) {
     int n=1050622;
     float datos[][] = new float[n][8];




    Scanner sc1,sc2,sc3,sc4,sc5,sc6,sc7,sc8;
    try {
        sc1 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Netbook\\f1.txt"));
        sc2 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Netbook\\f2.txt"));
        sc3 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Netbook\\f3.txt"));
        sc4 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Netbook\\f4.txt"));
        sc5 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Netbook\\f5.txt"));
        sc6 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Netbook\\f6.txt"));
        sc7 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Netbook\\f7.txt"));
        sc8 = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Users\\Netbook\\f8.txt"));



        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

            while (sc1.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][0] = sc1.nextFloat();

            }

            while (sc2.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][1] = sc2.nextFloat();

            }

            while (sc3.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][2] = sc3.nextFloat();

            }

            while (sc4.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][3] = sc4.nextFloat();                
            }

            while (sc5.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][4] = sc5.nextFloat();                
            }

            while (sc6.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][5] = sc6.nextFloat();                
            }

            while (sc7.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][6] = sc7.nextFloat();                
            }

            while (sc8.hasNextFloat()) {
                datos[i][7] = sc8.nextFloat();                
            }

        }

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            System.out.print("espectro "+ i+ " ");
            for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
                System.out.print(datos[i][j] + " ");
                //float datos[i] = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Netbook\\Exits");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

}

Comment: Please write a specific question about a specific error you get, pointing to the exact line in code where you need help.

Comment: First of all you want to change all `while (sc#.hasNextFloat())` to `if(sc#.hasNextFloat())`. Because right now you read all floats in the files during the first iteration of your for-loop, hence the result of 0.0 (I think).

Comment: I need help everywhere I think XD...so If someone can write a better solution I´ll be so pleased <3

Comment: Please ask specific questions, but never ask the volunteers to write your code for you. This type of request is not appropriate for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason behind you getting "0.0" all the time is that you use

```
while (sc1.hasNextFloat())
```

which makes you read all floats in each of the files during the first iteration of the for-loop. If you use `if` instead of `while` you should get the desired behavior.

As for writing the files I would suggest using a [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html) and the code would look something like this:

```
FileWriter fw;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    fw = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\Users\\Netbook\\Exits\\output" + i + ".txt"));
    for(int j=0;j<8;j++){
        fw.write(datos[i][j] + " ");
    }
    fw.flush();
    fw.close();
}
```

Also, remember to add a catch statement for the possible `IOException`.